# How can I force user to put a comment before closing the window in Internet explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, web

I have a web application and at some points I open a window for user so he could put a comment on it but I don't want the user to be able to close that window without leaving any comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that. You have no control on the browser for this. And all your users will hate you.

The best you can do is ask for a confirmation that user will leave the page.